# How to use the camera of one scene in another scene in Phaser

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework

I have a Bootstrap that I use to setup my camera

```
import Phaser from 'phaser'

export default class Bootstrap extends Phaser.Scene {
  private camera: Phaser.Cameras.Scene2D.Camera | null = null
  private zoomLevel: number = 1
  constructor() {
    super('Bootstrap')
  }

  private resizeCamera() {
    // Responsively set camera size to window size
    const width = window.innerWidth;
    const height = window.innerHeight;
    
    this.zoomLevel = (width > 600) ? 1.5 : 1;

    this.cameras.main.zoom = this.zoomLevel
    this.cameras.main.setSize(width, height);
    this.cameras.main.setScroll(0, 0);
  }

  create() {
    this.camera = this.cameras.main;

    this.resizeCamera();
    this.scale.on('resize', this.resizeCamera, this)
    
    // launch GameScene and pass in the camera
    this.scene.launch('GameScene', { 
      existingCamera: this.camera,
    });
  }
}
```

I am using `this.scene.launch` to run `GameScene` in parallel with `Bootstrap`

I am attempting to use the camera from `Bootstrap` in `GameScene`

```
import Phaser from 'phaser'

export default class GameScene extends Phaser.Scene {
  private player: Phaser.Physics.Arcade.Sprite | null = null;
  private camera: Phaser.Cameras.Scene2D.Camera | null = null
  constructor() {
    super('GameScene')
  }

  init(data: any) {
    this.camera = data.existingCamera;
  }

  create() {
    // Create player sprite and add physics
    this.player = this.physics.add.sprite(1200, 1200, 'adam', 18)

    this.camera?.setBounds(0, 0, 2400, 2400);
    this.camera?.startFollow(this.player, true);
  }
}
```

I am using the init function to get the camera from `Bootstrap` and use it for the camera in `GameScene`. I can `console.log` the `this.camera` in my `create` function and see that the scene parent is `Bootstrap`, but I don't see the my camera following my player. What am I doing wrong?

Also is it Ok to make a global camera to share across different scenes or is it better for each scene to have their own separate camera, even thought their functionalities are shared?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know you *can't/shouldn't* share a camera, because this could have many side effect.

Nevertheless if you want to do this, because you want to reuse settings, you could solve this with *inheritance* for example.

Just create a custom scene with your camera needs. And in the scenes where you need this camera *settings/features* inherit from the custom Scene, and in the other scenes, just inherit from the base `Phaser.Scene`.

**Here a possible demo:**

```
class MyCameraScene extends Phaser.Scene {
    constructor(name){
        super(name);
    }

    init(){
        this.resizeCamera();
        this.scale.on('resize', this.resizeCamera, this)
    }

    resizeCamera() {
        // Responsively set camera size to window size
        const width = window.innerWidth;
        const height = window.innerHeight;
        
        this.zoomLevel = (width > 600) ? 1.5 : 1;
    
        this.cameras.main.zoom = this.zoomLevel
        this.cameras.main.setSize(width, height);
        this.cameras.main.setScroll(0, 0);
    }
}

class Bootstrap extends MyCameraScene {
    // ...
}

class GameScene extends MyCameraScene { 
    // ...
}
```

Comment: @winnder_joiner I've noticed that my past 3 questions on Phaser have all been answered by you, you are a great help!

Comment: @dev_el you're welcome, I just check the `phaser-framework` tag, when I have some time, and if know a solution I try to help. _( I started doing this a while ago, to improve and practice my phaser skills )_ I'm glad I could help :)

Comment: For clarity, would the demo cause side effects by sharing reused camera settings? Although Bootstrap and GameScene extends MyCameraScene, does BootStrap and GameScene have their own separate cameras and it is only the settings of the camera that they share from MyCameraScene? It's not that the MyCameraScene camera is being used for Bootstrap and GameScene, right?

Comment: @dev_el there should not be any side effects, since each scene instance has it's own [CameraManager](https://photonstorm.github.io/phaser3-docs/Phaser.Cameras.Scene2D.CameraManager.html). The settings are only pulled from base class `MyCameraScene`.

Comment: Thank you for the clarity. Would you personally recommend this approach when scaling for hundreds of scenes? Or is there a more performant method you use?

Comment: @dev_el hundreds of scene sounds alot, I don't really know your use case. But if performance is no issue, using a custom base class to organize code is a good option.  _(If the scenes are not running all at the same time,there should not be an issue. I think)_

Comment: I was thinking of an MMORPG where you would need to scale hundreds of scenes. For example there is a town with many buildings. Each building is a new scene. I transition into a new scene and close the old one with `scene.start`. Appreciate your insight!

Comment: Since the scenes are not running _(are active)_ at the same time, this should not be an issue. _But_ for keeping code  slim and not having to write hundreds of scenes, I would have a _"building"-scene_, and on entering the the building, this scene _"building"-scene_ should be responsable for showing the building _(every building)._  If discuss ideas on phaser performance checkout [the phaser discourse](https://phaser.discourse.group/) or the [phaser discord](https://phaser.discourse.group/t/join-the-phaser-discord-server/13059)